# Show that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]< \infty \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\mathbb{P}[|X|>n]< \infty$

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

> Show that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]< \infty \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\mathbb{P}[|X|>n]< \infty$

I try the use the next inequality: if $Y$ is a non negative random variable then
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[Y>n] \leq \mathbb{E}[Y] \leq 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[Y>n]$$
Taking $Y:= X^2$ i get
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[X^2>n] \leq \mathbb{E}[X^2] \leq 1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[X^2>n]$$
but I'm not sure how to manipulate the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[X^2>n]$ to somehow make it appear $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\mathbb{P}[|X|>n]$

Any hint or help i will be very grateful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that $\mathbb{E}\left(X^{r}\right)=\int_{0}^{+\infty} r x^{r-1} \mathbb{P}(X&gt;x) d x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3373463/show-that-mathbbe-leftxr-right-int-0-infty-r-xr-1-mathbbp)

Comment: partially helps me since in this case my random variable is arbitrary and it is not hypothesized to be absolutely continuous.

Comment: Use Sangchul Lee's answer in above link and note that $\int_0^{\infty} xg(x)dx<\infty$ iff $\sum ng(n) <\infty$ for a decreasing function $g$.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest summation by parts.
$$2\sum_{n=1}^N n\mathbb{P}[|X|>n]\le 
\sum_{n=1}^N [(n+1)^2-n^2]\mathbb{P}[|X|>n]\\
= \sum_{n=2}^{N+1}n^2\mathbb{P}[|X|>n-1]- \sum_{n=1}^{N}n^2\mathbb{P}[|X|>n]\\ = 
 \sum_{n=2}^{N+1}n^2\mathbb{P}[n-1<|X|\le n]+(N+1)^2\mathbb{P}[|X|>N+1]\\ \le 4\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}(n-1)^2\mathbb{P}[n-1<|X|\le n]+\mathbb{E}[X^2]\\ \le  4\mathbb{E}[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[X^2]$$ Since $N$ is arbitrary we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\mathbb{P}[|X|>n]\le {5\over 2}\mathbb{E}[X^2]$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k P(X\gt k) = E\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty k I(X\gt k)\right) = E\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor X\rfloor-1} k = E\frac{\lfloor X\rfloor (\lfloor X\rfloor-1)}{2}
$$
whence
$$
EX^2\lt\infty \iff \sum_{k=0}^\infty k P(X\gt k)\lt\infty
$$